# Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey() returns null

Tags: c#, registry

I get a null back from this attempt to access the Windows Registry:

```
using (RegistryKey registry = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyPath))
```

keyPath is `SOFTWARE\\TestKey`

The key is in the registry, so why is it not finding it under the Local Machine hive?

Comment: Are you properly escaping KeyPath?  Is it "SOFTWARE\\TestKey", and not "SOFTWARE\TestKey"?

Comment: yes, I posted it wrong.  It is actually setup to use \\

Comment: So this has worked on my boss's PC just fine.  No reason why it should not here.  I gave asp.net account access to it since I'm running the VS web server and still returns null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comment to Dana you said you gave the ASP.NET account access. However, did you verify that that is the account that the site in running under? Impersonate and the anonymous access user can be easy to overlook.

UNTESTED CODE:

```
Response.Clear();  
Response.Write(Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName);  
Response.End();
```

Comment: How can I figure out which account the site is running under without having to write code to expose?

Comment: well the above is generally how i troubleshoot account issues although i do add a check in that it is coming from my ip address so that not just everyone can see it.

Answer (score 68):

It can happen if you are on a 64-bit machine. Create a helper class first (requires .NET 4.0 or later):

```
public class RegistryHelpers
{

    public static RegistryKey GetRegistryKey()
    {
        return GetRegistryKey(null);
    }

    public static RegistryKey GetRegistryKey(string keyPath)
    {
        RegistryKey localMachineRegistry
            = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine,
                                      Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem
                                          ? RegistryView.Registry64
                                          : RegistryView.Registry32);

        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyPath)
            ? localMachineRegistry
            : localMachineRegistry.OpenSubKey(keyPath);
    }

    public static object GetRegistryValue(string keyPath, string keyName)
    {
        RegistryKey registry = GetRegistryKey(keyPath);
        return registry.GetValue(keyName);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string keyPath = @"SOFTWARE\MyApp\Settings";
string keyName = "MyAppConnectionStringKey";

object connectionString = RegistryHelpers.GetRegistryValue(keyPath, keyName);

Console.WriteLine(connectionString);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: It should be noted that this answer requires .NET 4.0 or higher.

Comment: On 64-bit Windows there is two regedit utilities.
C:\Windows\System32\regedt32.exe and C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regedt32.exe. Each one gives you a different RegistryView

Comment: Is there any way to do this in .NET 3.5?

Comment: Thanks. Saved my time.

Comment: The 64-bit check isn't required. From MSDN: `If you request a 64-bit view on a 32-bit operating system, the returned keys will be in the 32-bit view.`

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to change it from

```
using (RegistryKey registry = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyPath))
```

to

```
using (RegistryKey registry = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Default).OpenSubKey(keyPath))
```

(Use `RegistryKey` instead of `Registry` , add the `RegistryView`, and put the hive-Local Machine as a method parameter.)

Comment: RegistryView.Default didn't work for me, I used what was specified in the most popular answer (but I like this answer's conciseness): Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem                                         ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32

Comment: Yeah, I think when you're going between 32-bit & 64-bit it makes a difference, so you have to specify which one. So adding that in, in place of `RegistryView.Default`, is a good idea.