# Getting a specific branch and all its values in the registry

Tags: c#, registry

I want to be able to get all the value pairs under a location in the registry, like:

```
 RegistryKey printerkey =
                settingsRegKey.OpenSubKey("\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Print\\Printers\\DevModes2\\Settings");
```

I can select Registry.LocalSystem, etc, but how do I then get to a specific branch (like above)?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, object> keyValuePairs;
using (var settingsRegKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Print\\Printers\\DevModes2\\Settings"))
{
       var valueNames = settingsRegKey.GetValueNames();
       keyValuePairs = valueNames.ToDictionary(name => name, settingsRegKey.GetValue);
}
```

Comment: You should also check if the settingRegKey is not null. The key might not exists. If the settingRegKey is not null then you can call GetValueNames.

Comment: If you're on 64bit machine, use this approach to open `Registry.LocalMachine`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13190185/244353