# NullReferenceException when trying to set registry permissions with C#

Tags: c#, permissions, registry

I'm trying to set the below permissions on a registry key. But I get a NullReferenceException error when it tries. Being a novice makes this tuff. Throw in permissions (which have always confused me) and I'm stumped. Can someone tell me why I'm getting this? Thanks.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Security.AccessControl;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
           string user = "Everyone";

           RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\123Test", true);

           rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(user,
               RegistryRights.FullControl | RegistryRights.TakeOwnership,
               InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit,
               PropagationFlags.None,
               AccessControlType.Allow));

           rk.SetAccessControl(rs);
       }
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's failing to get the RegistryKey rk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is causing you error

```
 RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\123Test", true);
```

Place a debugger here and see if it has value or it is null. If it is null check that path is valid. If it is valid do it like this

```
RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\123Test", true);
```

Comment: Thank you. The debugger tip was what I was forgetting.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@"\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\123Test"
```

> (double '\')

If not, try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268715/registry-localmachine-opensubkey-returns-null).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the nullreference exception is on the RegistryKey `rk` itself.

Is your application running as a 32-bit or 64-bit application? You shouldn't need to specify the Wow6432Node part and should just be able to reference `@"\SOFTWARE\123Test`