# Reading registry key

Tags: c#, registry

I have an application that compiles and debugs fine on a Win 7 (X86) machine. It installs and runs fine on a Windows 7 (X64) machine but if I try to debug after compiling I get an exception. Here is the code that throws the exception:

```
 public static string ReadLocalMachineRegistryKeyValue(string stringSubKey, string stringValue)
    {
        string stringReadValue = "";
        try
        {
            RegistryKey regKey;
            regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(stringSubKey);
            if (regKey != null)
            {
                stringReadValue = regKey.GetValue(stringValue).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("No such Subkey found.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return stringReadValue;
    }
```

Any Idea why this will compile and run after installation but it will not debug on a 64 bit machine? It may be important to note that the value being assigned to the regKey variable is accurate when hovering over it. The regKey never picks up the value, it remains null.

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: The assigned Exception "No such subkey found" is all I can see.

Comment: Why would the variable regKey stay null even though the value is accurate for Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(stringSubKey)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13190185/43846 ?

Comment: HKey_Local_Machine//Software//XXX

Comment: There are two sets of registry entries on x64 machines, one is the downward compatible x86 part. Search for Wow6432Node

Comment: I did. No Key there. I guess I am confused because I can install this software on the PC and it runs just fine. This only happens if I try to run it in MSVS 2010 as debug